# Who should I talk to about my resignation outside of work?

Tags: resignation, sickness, mental-health

Last year I started facing a whole raft of workplace issues. There isn't one in particular that I can frame a question around rather it's a holistic situation, there are many factors I can list, but the question isn't about that.

I have no family support and no close friends or confidents

Early in the year I started preparing my cv and looking at he job market.

Then the pandemic hit.

Suddenly I had to deal with working from home and getting set up and then being productive, Schooling two separate curriculums, with follow ups and dealing with the schools, that took my mind off the real isolation.

Looking for another job got seriously parked, as I dealt with those issues.

My mental health has taken a serious hit along the way

I've now decided to hand in my notice as I really can't cope any longer. I've booked a consultants appointment and I do know that after I describe things to the doctor, I'll be signed off

Three years ago I was signed off for 12 weeks due to mental health from DVDA.

I don't have faith in the human resources department after my last experience.

My management line is line manager -> head of -> CEO, again I have no faith in workplace support or understanding from my line manager or his manager, they didn't want to talk about it and barely acknowledged it.

As with my GP, the CEO will be understanding and accepting of my resignation

How can I find an actual human being to talk my decision to resign through with?

Comment: I'm sorry about your painful situation, but it's unclear what you actually want. You want to "talk this through" but to what purpose? It seems like you already made your decision. Are you just looking for a sympathetic ear ? Career advice ? Mental health advice ?

Comment: I would suggest that given that this sounds that distressing and a distressing decision to make, seek out occupational therapy available on the NHS in the UK https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/occupational-therapy/

Comment: @Ourjamie and months-long waiting least in most regions I fear. Op, as much as I feel for you and hope you can find support (maybe look for online support groups via google) I have to VTC as this isn't really a question we can answer here.

Comment: @Tymoteusz Paul yes I concur with your point, but with the OPp seeing a GP, there is a possiblity that that could be fastracked.OP please speak at length with your GP about your options for treatment eg Steps to Wellbeing

Comment: I regularly see a CBT therapist about work-induced anxiety. It's helping a lot and I wish I had started earlier.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I find an actual human being to talk my decision to resign through with?

Many companies have psychological counseling as part of the benefits package. Obviously this depends on where you are and how mental health services fit into the healthcare framework, but go through your employee benefits book to see what is in there.

Everyone I know has some kind of therapy benefit.

Comment: the company pmi offers cbt, which I have done on the past